# Не могу задеплоить телеграм-бота написанного на JAVA на Heroku

Tags: java, heroku

Написал простейшего бота на JAVA для Telegram и хочу залить его на Heroku. Следую инструкциям на официальном сайте

```
$ heroku login
$ git clone https://github.com/vladPiyrwaf/my_first_telegram
$ cd my_first_telegram
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
```

В конце выводит такое сообщение: Verifying deploy... done.
И вроде бы как никаких ошибок не выдает и программа задеплоена, но она не работает. И я не знаю, в чем проблема

Вот ссылка на проект, который я пытаюсь задеплоить:
https://github.com/vladPiyrwaf/my_first_telegram

Вот что я пишу в Procfile:

```
worker: java -jar target/recollect-bot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.recollect.Bot
```

Вот, что у меня в pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my_first_telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_first_telegram</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>vlad.telegram.bot.ver1.Bot</mainClass>
                            <name>workerBot</name>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

UPD:
Благодаря людям из комментариев я смог задеплоить бота.
На команду `$ heroku ps:scale web=1` показывает, что экземпляр приложения работает, Но сам бот в телеграмме не реагирует ни на какие команды.

Команда `$ heroku logs --tail` показывает только:

```
2019-02-08T21:46:10.352680+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: Самое время проверить, что в логах.

Comment: Для меня работает эта команда web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar  target/blablabla.jar. аргумент порта должен быть указан, плюс не worker, а web должно быть указано. Так же у меня установлен локально хероку и в помнике соответсвенно ничего нет. Так же вам лучше проверить логи с помощью команды heroku logs -t.

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov получилось задеплоить бота, показывает что один экземпляр программы работает, но сам бот не отвечает. Но порт я оставил, как написали вы $PORT

Comment: То есть проблема деплоя решилась, а теперь проблема в программе?

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov Честно говоря я не очень понимаю, в чем именно проблема. Тем более в heroku пишет, что программа скомпилирована и ошибок вроде нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Собери проект "mvn package";
2. В папке \target\bin должны появиться скрипты
3. В pom.xml у тебя указан workerBot, поэтому в Procfile пиши: "worker: sh target/bin/workerBot";
4. Тип процесса "worker" в Procfile  указывается если бот использует Long Polling, если Webhook, то запись другая.
5. Дальше по инструкции на сайте heroku.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!